What determines the mechanical advantage of a lever?
This question is more specific than it seems. I am doing a mechanics-related project in class and we are learning about the functions of levers. Basically, I am confused as to what determines the mechanical advantage of a lever. Online resources relate this to the law of the lever (effort force x effort arm=resistance force x resistance arm). However, I thought this law applied to how to balance a lever, not how to determine mechanical advantage. If this is the case, then how can we relate the law of the lever and mechanical advantage to a second law (effort force x effort distance=resistance force x resistance distance)? I know my thoughts may seem jumbled, but I'm essentially asking how the two above laws and the concept of mechanical advantage can be tied together cohesively.

What grade does this apply to?  The question can be easily answered, but the answer needs to be within the context of your current level of education.

I am currently in eighth grade, so I am very new to this kind of stuff.


If this is the case, then how can we relate the law of the lever and
mechanical advantage to a second law (effort force x effort
distance=resistance force x resistance distance)?

For a simple lever with a fulcrum, both laws will give you the mechanical advantage of the lever.
Uing the "Law of the lever":
Mechanical advantage = $\frac{\text {Length of input lever}}{\text{Length of output lever}}$
Using the "virtual work theorem":
Mechanical advantage = $\frac{\text{Effort distance}}{\text{Reistance distance}}$
The second method is based on conservation of energy i.e. (work in) = (work out) and is more generally applicable and can be applied universally to systems with mechanical advantage such as gear and pulley systems.
For example. If you pull the string of of a pulley system and it moves twice the distance that the output end moves, then the mechanical advantage is 2, because a force of one unit at the input produces twice the force at the output.
If the perimeter of an input gear moves twice the distance of the perimeter of an output gear , then the force is doubled at perimeter of the output gear and the mechanical advantage is 2.
For a more detailed explanation of the virtual work theorem see my answer to a related question: How are gears and levers related?

There is a principle of physics known as conservation of energy.  In physics, work is defined as a force multiplied by a distance through which that force acts, and work is known to be equivalent to an amount of energy that was expended in performing some task.  This means that when it comes to levers, the force acting on the effort arm multiplied by the distance that the effort arm travels, must equal the force acting on the resistance arm multiplied by the distance that the resistance arm travels.  In other words, "effort force x effort distance=resistance force x resistance distance" is a consequence of conservation of energy.

Thanks! Both these concepts make sense. However, I am also wondering how the two laws are related and what they apply to.

You need to ask your teacher to go into more detail.  Also, as you learn more, particularly more math, the explanations will make a lot more sense.
